# Copying the background color of an HTML element

Tags: gwt

I'd like to set the background color of an HTML element to the background color of another HTML element. This needs to happen at runtime using Javascript. I tried the following but it fails silently (the background color remains unaltered):

```
DOM.setElementProperty(element, "backgroundColor", "document.getElementById('country').style.backgroundColor");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but I would try

```
element.getStyle().setBackgroundColor(DOM.getElementById("country").getStyle().getBackgroundColor());
```

Comment: @RileyLark what should I do when it's not a `backgroundColor` but `BackgroundImage`?

Comment: @RileyLark I'm using this but it doesn't help: `element.getStyle().setBackgroundImage("images/myImage.png");`

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using a JS framework (jQuery, MooTools, etc), it should be as simple as something like (all code untested):

```
$("div2").attr("background") = $("div1").attr("background")
```

I normally just run with a framework (because I'm already using it elsewhere), but basic JavaScript should also be pretty simple as well, something along the lines of:

```
getElementByID("div2").setAttribute('background') = getElementByID("div1").getAttribute('background')
```

or

```
getElementByID("div2").Attribute('background') = getElementByID("div1").Attribute('background')
```

One thing I noticed in a quick reference search, though, is that the basic JavaScript method isn't consistent across browsers (IE seems to be quirky). Just something to keep in mind on that front.

Comment: I'm looking for a GWT-specific solution, if possible. If it's another possible, that's another matter.

Comment: Ah, missed that, since it was only in the tag.